# How to show "||" operator in a Markdown table?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I'm trying to show `||` in a GitHub readme page, but these `|` are used for creating columns in the table. How can I use this `||` so it doesn't mean a column?

| op | dec |
| --- | --- |
| && | AND |
|  |  | OR |

I tried `\` before the `|` character, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Yes you just have to escape "\" your pipes before you type them \|\|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an escaping backslash (`\`) before *each* pipe character (any un-escaped pipe would be treated as part of the table), like so:

```markdown
| Operator | Description |
|----------|-------------|
| &&       | AND         |
| \|\|     | OR          |
```

Result:

| Operator | Description |
| --- | --- |
| && | AND |
| || | OR |

Although I'd suggest marking them with inline code blocks:

Markdown:

```markdown
| Operator | Description |
|----------|-------------|
| `&&`     | AND         |
| `\|\|`   | OR          |
```

(It looks wrong on StackOverflow, but works correctly with GitHub's parser.)

Comment: that is weird. I paste this code in Readme github, but instead of || It only shows a back tick ` .

Comment: @Ehsan Hmmmm well isn't that interesting...